# why do my images change position when rolled over?

Tags: javascript, css, effects

I have a row of buttons (6 six) al same size. When each one is rolled over..

```
<img src="home.jpg" onmouseover="HomeAct(this)" onmouseout="Home(this)"/>

function HomeAct(obj){
    obj.src='webseparada/home.png';
}

function Home(obj){
    obj.src='webseparada/home.jpg';
}
```

home.jpg is a regular rectangle

home.png is a folder where label es is the button (home.jpg)

---

Here is why button1 sends all reimaing button the  next line.
When i sept in button 2 it doesn't move button1, but it goes down a line and sends al remaining another line, can anyone tell me if this can be corrected by css?

Thank you very much

Comment: Any chance the two images are different sizes?

Comment: It's possible you're seeing a loading stutter if you're not preloading the .png version of the image.  What happens if you define a width and height attribute on your `<img>` tag?

Comment: Yes, they are. But It should be a problem

Comment: It works properly on button 1 but it goes bad with the others
#home{padding-left:82px;padding-right:6px;}
#button2{padding-right:6px;}
#button2:hover{padding-left:82px;padding-right:6px;}

Comment: Pat, no I can't the second image is much bigger than the first but this is no t problem beacuse it works on button 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the image sizes are the same? It would make sense if they weren't. You can also explicitly specify the image sizes through css to force them to be consistent.

Comment: Good answer!  I'd likely also add in that Ignacio can set height/width attributes in the <img> tag.

Comment: Can I specify sizes and postions through css?

Comment: Yes. width and height properties.

Comment: Yes But still when the button turns into the "label of the folder" it moves from position the other buttons